# Use parse.com in android app

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm new in android developer and I use parse.com in my first android app.
My problem is when the user singup to the app, the user save in the core. but then the app  crashes.

This is my code:

```
save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!(password.getText().toString().equals(againPassword.getText().toString()))) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have mistake in password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    ParseUser newUser = new ParseUser();
                    newUser.put("name", firstName.getText().toString());
                    newUser.put("lastName", lastName.getText().toString());
                    newUser.setEmail(email.getText().toString());
                    newUser.setUsername(userName.getText().toString());
                    newUser.setPassword(password.getText().toString());
                    newUser.put("rosterArray", rosterArray);
                    myParse parse = new myParse();
                    try {
                        parse.saveUserInParse(newUser);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }

        });
```

The code of methed 'saveUserInParse' is

```
 public void saveUserInParse(ParseUser newUser)
{
    newUser.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                AlertDialog.Builder singUpSucceed = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                singUpSucceed.setTitle("Sing up succeed!!!");
                singUpSucceed.setCancelable(true);
                singUpSucceed.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert11 = singUpSucceed.create();
                alert11.show();
            } else {
                String theMessage = e.getMessage();
                AlertDialog.Builder singUpSucceed = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                singUpSucceed.setTitle("Sing up feild!!!");
                singUpSucceed.setMessage(theMessage);
                singUpSucceed.setCancelable(true);
                singUpSucceed.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert11 = singUpSucceed.create();
                alert11.show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

What did I do wrong? This problam is also in login method.

Thank you.

Comment: what says the logcat?

Comment: When I puss the RegisterButton I get this logcat:
12-01 17:15:39.455 1393-1393/efraimremez.rostersystem I/Choreographer: Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: can you post your entire logcat?That line doesn't show an error

Comment: where is your save.setOnClickListener method ? inside your onCreate method?

Comment: I enitire all the logcat in new answer. and the save.setOnClickListener method is inside the onCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my demo project for parse [Sample Parse](https://github.com/rahulparihar09/SampleParse), you an use for refrence.